# Error using proguard Retrofit2 and GSON Converter

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I'm creating a native android app and I want to release it.

I'm using retrofit and Gson converter. Also a search view.
For the release I have set up the proguard rules, as suggested by retrofit:

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
-dontwarn javax.**
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }

# Retrofit
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions
```

In retrofit I use:
ApiUtils.java

```
 public static PBTService getPBTService(String BASE_URL) {
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(PBTService.class);
    }
```

Service.java

```
import br.com.adley.ipubg.data.Player;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.Path;

public interface PBTService {
    String API_KEY = "MYKEY";
    @Headers(API_KEY)
    @GET("profile/pc/{nickname}")
    Call<Player> getPlayerStatsByNickname(@Path("nickname") String nickname);

}
```

RetrofitClient.java

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

In debug mode or when proguard is offline it works perfectly.
But when I generate signed app with proguard and do a GET using retrofit, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class br.com.adley.ipubg.a.a for method a.a
```

I've try a lot of proguard configs. I might think the error is related with GSON converter.

I've already tried:

```
#My retrofit service package
-keep public class br.com.adley.ipubg.data.** {public private protected *;}
-keep public class br.com.adley.ipubg.activities.MainActivity.** {public private protected *;}
#others configs
-keep class com.google.gson.** { ; }
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }:
-keep public class com.google.gson.**
-keep public class com.google.gson.** {public private protected *;}
```

**UPDATE**

I've add the GSON configs to pro-guard:

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class br.com.adley.ipubg.data.models.MatchHistory.** { *; }
-keep class br.com.adley.ipubg.data.models.Player.** { *; }
-keep class br.com.adley.ipubg.data.models.Season.** { *; }
-keep class br.com.adley.ipubg.data.models.Stats.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

But still get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class br.com.adley.ipubg.data.models.Player for method a.a
```

Comment: Gson also has proguard rules you seem to be missing https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check it.

Comment: Sadly, still not working :(

Comment: You need to add keep class for your models that's the issue

Comment: Is not related to those library, your log clearly says it not able to find your modal as it will be renamed when progaurd is enabled

Comment: I've add my models that using gson for ex: -keep class br.com.adley.ipubg.data.models.Player.** { *; } - But still getting error

Comment: I don't know if it's the right way, I just follow the GSON example.

Comment: `for method a.a` indicates that your setter/getter methods are being rewritten, but your fields don't match

Comment: Hey guys, I check it again and there was a wrapper that create some objectes that use the models. There was the error. I solved. Thanks Guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After check the comments, I've add a GSON proguard rules and retrofit.

Also, be careful if you have a wrapper that uses your models, it will cause convert errors.

My final pro-guard rules, now working, is:

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}

-dontwarn org.ini4j.** # Ignore warning for missing classes in ini4j
-dontwarn javax.**
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }

# Retrofit
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class br.com.adley.ipubg.data.** { *; }
-keep class br.com.adley.ipubg.wrapper.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Thanks all guys for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue as OP, after research for multiple sources, I added these 3 lines to my pro-guard config file and they solved my problem:

```
-keep class com.squareup.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
```